# Determining what Page a Component is on (Apollo / GraphQL Pagination)

Tags: javascript, pagination, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have X items / components that I get from my graphql server, and I'm showing them in separate pages (and am fetching them depending on what page the user is on). Each page holds 20 items.

I want the user to be able to also type in the name of a specific item, and go to that item. But how do I know what page that Item is on? I might want to re-render my app & fetch the items on page-4, because that's where the users item is located. Is there a nice solution to find something like this out with Apollo?